# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.Device' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an APS.Net 6.0 web API where I'm referring to `Microsoft.Graph` v5.18.0 to inject a Graph API client and make some Graph calls later in some controllers. However, when added the `Microsoft.Graph` package to my project I started seeing the following error message when hitting the `app.UseEndpoints(e=> e.MapControllers())` in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.Device' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.Device' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Synergix.LEDR.API.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoint) in C:\Users\96170\source\repos\LEDR\src\ServerSide\APIs\Synergix.LEDR.API\Startup.cs:line 140
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Synergix.LEDR.API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\96170\source\repos\LEDR\src\ServerSide\APIs\Synergix.LEDR.API\Startup.cs:line 140
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Synergix.LEDR.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\96170\source\repos\LEDR\src\ServerSide\APIs\Synergix.LEDR.API\Program.cs:line 20
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.Device' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=5.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

It is confusing because I'm not using `Microsoft.Graph.Device` namespace anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Graph.Device` is not a namespace. The two possibilities are the namespace `Microsoft.Graph.Devices`, but according to your exception it likes to use the *type* `Microsoft.Graph.Models.Device`. If your solution / project was upgraded vom Graph SDK v4 to v5, the namespace of the type has changed from `Microsoft.Graph` to `Microsoft.Graph.Models`.

So at a first step, ensure that all your projects are using the v5 SDK of the Graph library and not any project still relies on the v4 SDK. Also scan your whole code for usage of `Device` or (if this list is too long) for the line `using Microsoft.Graph;` and check within these files the usage of `Device`.

My guess would be, that one of your controllers (in its own project) has a request or response object, that has a property of the type `Microsoft.Graph.Device` and this project still references the v4 SDK, while your startup application already references the v5 SDK.

Be aware, if this is true, your job isn't done by simply adopting the project references and changing the namespaces. The biggest problem is, that the Graph objects no longer can be simply de- / serialized from or to JSON by using System.Text.Json. If you try, you get unexpected results, cause the v5 SDK uses another abstraction for serialization, which prevents to simply use a Graph object with System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, 1. This is not an upgrade from v4 to v5, 2. I have one controller that uses another helper method that returns a Microsoft.Graph.Models.Device object, 3. I'm not serializing the Device object back to the response but thanks for that point too

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Issue by removing `Microsoft.Graph` package and installing `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` instead.

`Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` is a wrapper library that simplifies the process of authenticating with Microsoft Graph and making requests to the Graph API. So in my case I had make some minor changes to the code to make it working again, but that's not big.

`Microsoft.Graph` should still work though but I don't know why that didn't happen in my case. If anyone have an explanation for that please leave it in the comments below.